# Delphi 2006 - routine parameter untyped 

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006

It is possible to have a parameter in a routine which can be in the same time either an type, either an string? I know I can accomplish this by overloading a routine, I ask if it possible to do it in another way.

Assume that I have this type - TTest = (t1,t2,t3). I want to have a routine which accepts a parameter of type TTest, but in the same time to be a String, so I can call it  myproc(t1) or myproc('blabla')

Comment: See ["untyped parameters"](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/Parameters_%28Delphi%29#Untyped_Parameters) in the docs.

Comment: @sertac If  untyped parameters were used, how would the function determine what type had actually been passed?

Comment: @David - I don't care, that's not the question <g>. He can pass another parameter (ThatsAString: Boolean)..

Comment: @Sertac Not according to the question. The required call signature has only one parameter.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - please post it so I can vote your answer.

Comment: @RBA - Thanks, but I don't quite like that solution either myself. I just thought it should be mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even this can be easily accomplished with overloaded functions, considering it's a good exercise, based on David Hefferman's and Sertac Akyuz answers I made a small example to test both solutions. It is not perfect, it only shows both possibilities.

```
unit Unit4;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs;

type
  ttest = (t1,t2);
  TForm4 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    function my(aVar:Variant):String;
    function MyUntype(const aVar):String;
  end;

var
  Form4: TForm4;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm4 }

procedure TForm4.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var aTestTypeVar : ttest;
    aString : String;
begin
 my(t1);
 my(t2);
 my('ssss');
//with untyped params
 aString := 'aaaa';
 MyUntype(aString);
 aTestTypeVar := t1;
 aString := IntToStr(Ord(aTestTypeVar));
 MyUntype(aString);//can not be a numeral due to delphi Help
end;

function TForm4.my(aVar: Variant): String;
begin
 showmessage(VarToStr(aVar));//shows either the string, either position in type
end;

function TForm4.MyUntype(const aVar): String;
begin
 //need to cast the parameter  
 try
  ShowMessage(pchar(aVar))
 except
  showmessage(IntToStr(Ord(ttest(aVar))));
 end;
end;

end.
```

Also I know that Variants are slow and must be used only needed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - it is not 100% perfect. It is just a quick example.

Comment: Sertac's suggestion was that you also pass a parameter to identify the type, if using untyped params. Also, to my mind the issue with variants is not speed, but the lack of compile time type checking. Sometimes you want runtime checking, but in this case I think you want compile time checking. Also, well done for writing out some code. That gives a nice context to explore the options and understand the pros and cons.

Comment: At this moment I needed a small example to explain this to a co-worker. So, this was a quick and dirty one :). I agree with you on the compile time type checking.

Answer (score 5):

You should use an overloaded function.

You already have the perfect solution to the problem and there is no need to look for a different way to do this. You could try with a single function that receives a `Variant`, but then that function will also receive anything which means that the following would also be legal:

```
myproc(0.5);
myproc(intf);
myproc(-666);
```

Using an overload allows you to maintain compile time type safety and there is absolutely no loss of generality in using an overload.

Comment: +1 you are right. I just want to make a small exercise, to find another way to do it.